# SVG to PNG by PythonMagickWand

Tags: magickwand

I try to convert SVG to PNG. Result picture has a white background I need transparent.

Sample of code:

```
wand = NewMagickWand()
MagickReadImage(wand,tmp_file_name)
transparentColor = NewPixelWand()
PixelSetMagickColor(transparentColor, 'none')
MagickSetBackgroundColor(wand, transparentColor)
MagickWriteImage(wand,new_filename)
```

if I do in command-line:

```
convert -background 'transparent' ./media/2222222.svg ./media/2222222.png
```

I've got a transparent picture.

Comment: Did you try `PixelSetMagickColor(transparentColor, 'white')`?

Comment: I did, same result, background is white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used subprocess and I got what I want

```
args = ['convert', '-background', 'transparent', './media/2222222.svg', './media/2222222.png',]
result = subprocess.call(args)
```

Comment: @macpuk: Can you provide more code on how you implemented the subprocess? Did you use `MagickCommandGenesis()`?